# Passing in REF in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, ora-00907

I got ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. I believe I have right pairs of parenthesis. I'm trying to pass a reference of service type to employee type when I insert an employee record.

```
INSERT INTO Person VALUES 
 (FullTimeEmployeeType (1, 
                       NameType('David', 'R', 'Jones'),
                       'M',  
                       AddressType('123 somewhere', '', 'London', 'UD', '84042'), 
                       '8030349092','',
                       '1978-05-26', 
                       REF <servicerType>, 
                       40000)
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I count 4 "("  and 3 ")"

Comment: You're right - I missed the scroll so the one after 'Jones' wasn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the [REF expects brackets](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14260/adobjbas.htm#sthref387) rather than a < >

```
SELECT REF(p) 
  FROM person_obj_table p
```